# If a ring $R$ with $1$ has characteristic $0$, then it has a subring isomorphic to the integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If a ring $R$ with $1$ has characteristic $0$, show that $R$ contains a subring that is in 1-1 correspondence with $\mathbb{Z}$ (this subring is called the prime subring of $R$).

Let $f: R\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, if $x \in R$ then $x\mapsto ?$. 
As I define $f$ so that it is a 1-1 correspondence? Which subring should consider?

Comment: You actually want an injective ring morphism in the other direction: $f:\mathbb{Z} \to R$.

Comment: Once you understand how this problem works, here is a bonus problem: If $R$ is a field of characteristic $0$, then $R$ contains a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 5):

Define $f\colon \Bbb Z \to R$ by $f(n) = n1$. This morphism is injective because $R$ has characteristic zero. The subring you're looking for is ${\rm Im}(f) = f[\Bbb Z]\subseteq R$.

Answer (score 3):

You want a subring, so you need a map $\phi: \Bbb Z\to R$, send $1_{\Bbb Z}\mapsto 1_R$. If it is not injective, it has a non-trivial kernel. To see it is injective, let $k\in\ker \phi$ be the smallest positive integer in $\ker \phi$. Then if $r\in R$ we have that $k\cdot r=0$ for all $r$, hence $R$ has positive characteristic, so no such $k$ exists, i.e. $\ker\phi =\{0\}$ and the map is injective, hence $R$ has a subring isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.